# How to gitignore sub-directories under parent folder?

Tags: git, directory, gitignore

I have the following structure:

```
FolderA
-FolderB
--FolderB1
---FileB1
---FileB2
--FolderC
---FolderC1
----FileC1
```

Suppose if I am working under FolderC1 and wanted to gitignore Folder B and below contents?

Comment: “Working under” `FolderC1`?  What does your current working directory have to do with anything?

Comment: Ignores already work that way.

Comment: When I give git status in the FolderC1. It shows all changes under FolderB also which I don't want. When I added this ../../FolderB it did not work. How to ignore other subdirectories in a parent folder?

Comment: Put a `.gitignore` in `FolderA`.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Answer (score 0):

> When I give git status in the FolderC1. It shows all changes under FolderB also which I don't want

Simply add a path to [`git status`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status):

```
cd FolderA/FolderB/FolderC
git status .
```

That will show you changes only from the current folder (`C`) and below.
That has nothing to do with "gitignore", which would prevent elements of other folders to be tracked.